# Stop running method in managed bean when user stops listening for response

Tags: java, managed-bean

I have a web application built using JSF 2.2, where a user can upload a file which will then be validated.

The validation can sometimes take an extremly long time so that the user gets tired of listening and clicks something else on the site. When this happens I want the validation to stop but it just keeps running eventhough the user is no longer listening for a response.

I have been googleing for a while but can't find any suggestions on how to handle this. My validation method is in a viewscoped managed bean.

Any suggestions on how to solve this or what to look into?

Comment: 'When user stops listening for response' doesn't correspond to any TCP event at the server. Your server will just have to detect a failure to write to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your website and on what you want to achieve, I would suggest:

- If the fileupload is within a dialog, you can attach a listener to the dialog itself. When the listener is called just stop the validation progress in your bean.
- You can try to make the dialog modal, it prevents the user form clicking anywhere else on the page (except the experience users which are able to remove the modal, and the dialog from the document DOM by using e.g., Firebug or Developer Tools)
- The same applies for a [block ui](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) script.
- Imho the best approach would be to attach a [window.beforeunload listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) or something similar. This listener can then call a backing bean method to stop the validation.